# Can I use a hidden DataGridView column to manage a SQL Server VarBinary field?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a table that I want to store a byte array in a field. The byte array is about 20 bytes (160 bits) of key data.

I am using several `DataGridView` to manage this table and other tables for this application. I currently have a couple of routines that allow me to provide a SQL select string and the `DataGridView` allows the user to edit the data.

```
private void InitializeUsersDataGrid()
{
  string sql = "SELECT UserId, Enabled, AccessLevel, Name, KeyValue FROM Users";

  DataGridViewIntialize(dgvUsers, sql);
  dgvUsers.Columns[fdKeyValue].Visible = false;
}

private void DataGridViewIntialize(DataGridView dataGridView, string sql)
{
  dataGridViewInUse = dataGridView; // This is the current DataGridView
  OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);
  dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleDbConnection);
  OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);  //Creates SQL commands for IUD

  dataTable = new DataTable();
  dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
  bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable;

  dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource1;

  // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
  dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
  AddDeleteRefreshContextMenu(dataGridView);
}
```

I have a Save button that provides the validating and then calls `TableSave`.

```
private void TableSave()
{
  // Update the database with the user's changes.
  try {
    dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

When I added the `varbinary` field to the table it appeared in the `DataGridView` as a broken bitmap image. This didn’t concern me because I wasn’t going to display it anyway.

When I try and assign a new byte array to the call it generates a DataGridView Default Error Dialog.

```
/// <summary>
/// Change the password hash for the selected login
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void ChangePassword( DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // Request a new password with confirmation
  fPassword form = new fPassword();
  form.Confirm = true;
  DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
  if (dr == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Combine the UserID with the password to generate a new key
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] key;
    string p = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["UserId"].Value + form.Value;
    Data.PBK2DF2Hash.GenerateSaltAndKey(p, out salt, out key);
    if (dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[fdKeyValue].ValueType == key.GetType()) {
      // We do get this far Error occurs on the assignment in the next line
      dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[fdKeyValue].Value = key;
    } 
  }
}
```

> DataGridView Default Error Dialog
>
> The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:  System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
>    at
>   System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObjectInternal(Object value, Type
>   targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter
>   targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo,
>   Object formattedNullValue)
>    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObject(Object value, Type
>   targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter
>   targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo,
>   Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)
>    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetFormattedValue(Object value,
>   Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewCellStyle& cellStyle, TypeConverter
>   valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
>   DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
>
> To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

It appears that has to do with `CellFormatting` but I don’t know how to turn it off.

Adding this bit of code provides a simpler dialog with this error message:

> System.FormatException: Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type.

```
private void dgvUsers_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewColumn c = dgvUsers.Columns[fnKeyValue];
  if (c != null) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == c.Index) {
      if (e.Value != null) {
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
      }
      else
        e.FormattingApplied = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update #1** - Additional code using Ivan Stoev suggested method and shows the button cell that I used to solicit the password change.  It also adds saving the salt value.

The issue at this point is that when I hit the Change Password button I can open my password dialog, get the password. Generate the salt and key, save it to the datagrid cells for that row/s salt and keyValue.

If I do a `TableSave()` (see earlier code) these fields are not in the SQL server table unless I do a mouse click on a different row in the grid. That action seems to indicate the row is dirty and then the save will work.

I can also change one of the fields visible to the user before or after I change the password and the row will save.

```
private void InitializeUsersDataGrid()
{
  string sql = "SELECT UserId, Enabled, AccessLevel, Name, Salt, KeyValue FROM Users";

  AddAccessLevelColumn(dgvUsers);  //Add column if needed
  AddPasswordChangeColumn(dgvUsers);
  DataGridViewIntialize1(dgvUsers, sql);
  dgvUsers.Columns[UsersFieldName.fdAccessLevel].Visible = false;  //Hide the raw column from the database

  MoveAccessLevelColumn(dgvUsers, AccessLevelComboBoxColumn, AccessLevelColumnPosition);
  MoveAccessLevelColumn(dgvUsers, PasswordButtonColumn, PasswordColumnPosition);
}

private void DataGridViewIntialize1(DataGridView dataGridView, string sql)
{
  dataGridViewInUse = dataGridView; // This is the current DataGridView
  OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);
  dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleDbConnection);
  OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);  //Creates SQL commands for IUD

  dataTable = new DataTable();
  dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
  dataTable.Columns[Data.UsersFieldName.fdSalt].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
  dataTable.Columns[Data.UsersFieldName.fdKey].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
  bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable;

  dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource1;

  // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
  dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
  AddDeleteRefreshContextMenu(dataGridView);
}

private void AddPasswordChangeColumn(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
  // This column will remain unless manually removed, so it only needs to be added
  // the first time the DVG is initialized.

  if (dataGridView.Columns[PasswordButtonColumn] == null) {
    // creating new ComboBoxCell Column
    DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    btnColumn.Text = "Change Password";
    btnColumn.HeaderText = "Change Password";
    btnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    btnColumn.Name = PasswordButtonColumn;
    btnColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, btnColumn);
    // Add a CellClick handler to handle clicks in the button column.
    dataGridView.CellClick += dataGridView_CellClick;
  }
}

private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // Ignore clicks that are not on button cells.
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < dgvUsers.RowCount - 1 && e.ColumnIndex == dgvUsers.Columns[PasswordButtonColumn].Index) {
    ChangePassword(e);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Change the password hash for the selected login
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void ChangePassword(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // Request a new password with confirmation
  fPassword form = new fPassword();
  form.Confirm = true;
  DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
  if (dr == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Combine the UserID with the password to generate a new key
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] key;
    string p = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Data.UsersFieldName.fdUserId].Value + form.Value;
    Data.PBK2DF2Hash.GenerateSaltAndKey(p, out salt, out key);
    var gridRow = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var dataRow = (DataRowView)gridRow.DataBoundItem;
    var value = dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdKey];
    dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdSalt] = salt;  //This assignment now works
    dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdKey] = key;
  }
}
```

**Update #2** Adding 'NotifyCurrectCell' Dirty to the 'ChangePassword' method notifies the grid that the cell needs to be saved without changing rows in the UI.

```
private void ChangePassword(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // Request a new password with confirmation
  fPassword form = new fPassword();
  form.Confirm = true;
  DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
  if (dr == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Combine the UserID with the password to generate a new key
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] key;
    string p = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Data.UsersFieldName.fdUserId].Value + form.Value;
    Data.PBK2DF2Hash.GenerateSaltAndKey(p, out salt, out key);
    var gridRow = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var dataRow = (DataRowView)gridRow.DataBoundItem;
    var value = dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdKey];
    dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdSalt] = salt;  //This assignment now works
    dataRow[Data.UsersFieldName.fdKey] = key;
    dgvUsers.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true); //Tells the UI that this row has changed and needs updating
  }
}
```

Comment: Your image form is not valid.  ImageFromStream() must be a valid image format otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: How do I tell the column it it is not an image?

Comment: Data Type are found in  System.Data.SqlDbType.  Binary should work.  To specify type you must add a parameter to your SQL Command.  The parameter contains the data type.

Comment: @jdweng I've tried adding a CAST, but that generally isn't working.  Did you mean something else?  `string sql = "SELECT UserId, Enabled, AccessLevel, Name, CAST(KeyValue AS BINARY) FROM Users`

Comment: You have to set the database column to binary.  The type will automatically be transferred to VS as binary.  You don't need a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because `DataGridView` creates by default [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) for `byte[]` data type.

Here are some options.

- A. Set [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false` and create the grid columns manually.
- B. If you don't really need that column in the grid, instead of trying to hide the grid column, do not create grid column at all. But how to achieve that? For class property one would use `Browsable(false)`, but this is `DataTable`. Well, although not documented, one can use [DataColumn.ColumnMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping(v=vs.110).aspx) property with `MappingType.Hidden` for the same purpose.

In your case, remove this line

```
dgvUsers.Columns[fdKeyValue].Visible = false;
```

and inside the `DataGridViewIntialize` method use

```
// ...
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
dataTable.Columns[fdKeyValue].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable;
// ...
```

You still can access your column data by using underlying data source like this

```
var gridRow = dgvUsers.Rows[...];
var dataRow = (DataRowView)gridRow.DataBoundItem;
var value = dataRow[fdKeyValue];
```

Comment: I had to add the Columns property to the statement to get access to the ColumnMapping property.  But that totally removed it from the grid so I couldn't change the the returned data.  Setting Visible to false allowed the data to exist internally and to at least try and make a change.

Comment: Why do you think if there is no column in the grid, the data does not exist? Since you are using data bound mode, the data is contained in your data table, not in a grid. Use [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, cast to `DataRowView` and here is your data with all columns.

Comment: The column is there when I use your syntax, but not when I use my original syntax. Using your syntax I can assign my array and it shows up in the table.  `dataRow[fdKeyValue] = key;`  My last issue is that the KeyValue field is written to the table only if I move the cursor to another cell after I write the data. Otherwise it doesn't know that that field is dirty.  Is there a flag I can set on the row so it will save?

Comment: If you post some code (event handlers etc.) showing what you are trying to do with "your syntax", I guess we'll be able to translate it :)

Comment: I've added some update code (**Update #1**) explaining a little further the current issue.

Comment: I added this line immediately after setting the salt and key data to the two hidden cells and saving works for that row every time. `dgvUsers.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);`